# How to select with dom a random child element from an element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

i started an interactive rating card.

The goal is to choose a number how you would rate and then to submit your answer.

i want to chose a number and then with and eventlistner to change the background of the div element of the choosen number from the current background to another color. So far i have the submit button and recive a thank you message on the card after the button.

this is the html of the 5 number you can choose to rate

```
 <div class="numbers">
          <div class="one">1</div>
          <div class="two">2</div>
          <div class="three">3</div>
          <div class="four">4</div>
          <div class="five">5</div>
        </div>
```

this is the css for example for the first div. All divs have the same css code

```
.one {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  color: var(--text-color);
  background-color: var(--background-color-body);

  border-radius: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

I tried with a for Loop to go through all the numbers and by clicking to change the backgroug color

this was the javascript code i tried

```
addEventListener('click', myFunction);
{
  function myFunction() {
    var drugi = document.querySelectorAll('.numbers div');
    for (i = 0; i <= element.length; i++) {
      element[i].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems wit your `.js` code. First, you have the function `myFunction` in a different scope than the event listener `addEventListener('click', myFunction)`. So to fix it just remove the keys that wrap it. Second, you are using the `element` before declaring it. And third, the loop will assign the same color to all the element. (Notice a background color `white` will be not noticed).

To fix it, just use the event delegation pattern on the parent (which is the div element with the class `numbers`) and check if the `target` is a `div` element with the class `number` and then change the background color.

```
const numbers = document.querySelector('.numbers')
numbers.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const target = event.target
  if (target.className === 'numbers') return
  target.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
})
```